# 502 Bad Gateway error and phpmyadmin not working after upload a huge data in database

Tags: mysql, cakephp, vps

I am working on Cakephp When i upload more than 25000 data in mysql its show 502 Gateway error at website and website not working. Also mysql not open properly. Also i have increased `memory_limit`. But still same issue.

Answer (score 1):

use command line for load big data

$mysql -u user -p

your passwd

$mysql: use your_db;

$mysql: source /your_path/your_base.sql;